# 'Hand' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm currently working on a Blackjack game, and as I currently have it structured, I have a Hand class that is a list of Card objects, and I am trying to reference a specific card in a hand.

```
def get_move(self):
    if self.balance > self.bet and not self.isSplit:
        if self.hand[0].point == self.hand[1].point:
```

The problem arises on that third line. I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 126, in <module>
     player.get_move()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/finalproject/human_player.py", line 29, in get_move
    if self.hand[0].point == self.hand[1].point:
TypeError: 'Hand' object does not support indexing
```

Why isn't it letting my index through the Hand? Here is the constructor to my Hand class:

```
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
```

EDIT: I do create Hand objects for each of the players in my main method:

```
# creating the dealer for the game    
dealer_hand = hand.Hand()
dan_the_dealer = dealer.Dealer(dealer_hand)

# for however many players you start with, add each new player to an array of players 
for i in range(num_players):
    player_name = input("\nWhat is Player %i's name?\n" % (i+1))
    new_hand = hand.Hand()
    new_player = human_player.HumanPlayer(player_name, starting_balance, 0, new_hand)
    players.append(new_player)
```

Comment: You don't happen to be redefining `hand` for the `Hand` object anywhere do you?

Comment: That error message indicates that `self.hand` is a `Hand` object rather than a list. Nothing in the code that you have shown would cause that to happen. Thus -- the problem lies in code that you are not showing. Since you aren't showing the code that contains the bug, there isn't much anyone can do to help.

Comment: I don't believe so. If I were to look for a sign of that, what would that look like?

Comment: You need to give a [mcve]

Comment: I believe I might have added something that might have caused this; see EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the dunder method getitem like so

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.hand[item]
```

Otherwise, when you try to access the index of the object, the Python interpreter doesn't really know what you want to do.

Wouldn't hurt to also define a dunder setitem too so that when you try this:

```
h = Hand()
h[0] = 1
```

then the interpreter will also need to access the `__setitem__` dunder method to perform the operation.

These methods are already defined in the builtin `list` object and that's why you can index seamlessly.
You could try to inherit them from the `list` class. That's up to you, but an example would begin like:

```
class Hand(list):
    ...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I was considering creating a "get_card" method earlier, but I forgot about dunder methods.